# Symfony2 Authentication Listener 403 Forbidden Response

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I am returning a Response object with the 403 status code while in an authentication listener.

The example I have followed is from [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-listener):

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setStatusCode(403);
$event->setResponse($response);
```

When this response is created, the browser (Chrome) shows the web browser error page:

```
Access to the web page was denied

You are not authorised to access the web page at http://project/access-denied. You may need to sign in.
```

What I would like it to do is display my own error twig error page from `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error403.html.twig` (as described in [this cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#customizing-the-404-page-and-other-error-pages)). But as the 403 response is already sent, it doesn't get that far.

I cannot throw an AccessDeniedException because this is an authentication failure, meaning there is no security token present which causes a fatal error.

I can throw an AuthenticationException but this only causes a 500 error, which displays the standard 500 error page.

The only way I can see to do this is to pass the twig service to the listener and add it to the response, like: `$response->setContent($twigRenderedError);` But this does seem like an ugly solution - possibly a flaw in the authentication layer of Symfony2?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't throw an `AccessDeniedException`. It's **the** exception to send a 403 error code.